# Cannot add "simplejwt.token_blacklist" to install apps

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Hi I'm having an issue with restframework_simplejwt library.
When I add blacklisting to installed apps ir returns me an error.

settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    ...
]
```

error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "token_blacklist_outstandingtoken" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "token_blacklist_outstandingtoken" ("user_id", "...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that after adding the app to `INSTALLED_APPS` I didn't `migrate` the changes .

`python manage.py migrate` and problem solved.

[Simple JWT docs](https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blacklist_app.html) gives us the necesary steps for this action.